# Polymorphism providing a class with the right variables (Architecture)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

This is going to be a bit tricky but it is really bothering me so I hope you will have the patience to follow along :)

Here is my very basic architecture:

[image]

So in the framework, I am creating I have `Actions` these currently have a list of `Conditions` or Considerations (same thing different name).

While each `Condition` share some of the same functionality  such as:

- Returning a float score
- Using an evaluation formula

They implement these in very different ways depending on the situation.

Take a look at the following code:

```
[CreateAssetMenu(fileName = "Consider my health vs max health",
    menuName = "AnAppGames/AI/Example/Decisions/Health Consideration")]
public class MyHealth : BaseConsideration
{
    private float health;
    public float maxHealth;

    public override float Consider<T>(BaseAiContext context, BaseAction action, T value)
    {
        health = value as float;
        return EvaluateValues(health / maxHealth);
    }

}
```

What you are looking at is my first attempt at making some sort of "reusable" `Consideration`.

Now in the continuation of my development, I had to make the following `Consideration`:

```
public class DistanceFromMe : BaseConsideration
{
    public float minRange;
    public float maxRange;

   
    private float ConsiderWithValues(Transform target, Transform caller)
    {
        return EvaluateValues(new FloatData(Vector3.Distance(target.transform.position, caller.position),
            minRange,
            maxRange).GetNormalizedData());
    }

    public override float Consider<T>(BaseAiContext context, BaseAction action, T value)
    {
        Transform target = value as Transform;
        if (target == null)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        return ConsiderWithValues(target.transform, context.transform);
    }

    public override float Consider(float x)
    {
        return EvaluateValues(new FloatData(x,
            minRange,
            maxRange).GetNormalizedData());
    }

}
```

And now the trouble begins I thought "This is not a scaleable solution" as soon as I need more than 1 generic parameter I am screwed and have to create additional overrides of this `Consider` function.

So what I need is somehow to add different types of parameters to the `Consideration` however these parameters will vary a lot.

Another problem I have with this is that when I loop through the list I won't be able to tell what parameters I needed and how to fulfill the needs of the `Consideration`.

I thought of different ways of dealing with this inside the editor but I have come up empty :(

Can anyone help me out with this architectural mess? :)

It is worth mentioning that at the current point each of these are ScriptableObjects I am not 100 set in the fact that they should be but I am just not sure how to deal with this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Move the Generic on to the BaseConsideration, and off of the method. Then define classes with the properties that each consideration will use.

```
public class BaseConsideration<T>
{
    public virtual float Consider(BaseAiContext context, BaseAction action, T value)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    // ... other base code here
}

public class MyHealthConsiderationProps
{
    public MyHealthConsiderationProps(float health, float maxHealth)
    {
        Health = health;
        MaxHealth = maxHealth;
    }
    public float MaxHealth { get; private set; }
    public float Health { get; private set; }
}

public class MyHealth : BaseConsideration<MyHealthConsiderationProps>
{
    public override float Consider(BaseAiContext context, BaseAction action,
         MyHealthConsiderationProps value)
    {
        return EvaluateValues(value.Health / value.MaxHealth);
    }
}

public class DistanceFromMe : BaseConsideration<Transform>
{
    public float minRange;
    public float maxRange;

    private float ConsiderWithValues(Transform target, Transform caller)
    {
        return EvaluateValues(new FloatData(Vector3.Distance(target.transform.position, caller.position),
                minRange,
                maxRange).GetNormalizedData());
    }

    public override float Consider(BaseAiContext context, BaseAction action, Transform value)
    {
        if (value == null)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        return ConsiderWithValues(value.transform, context.transform);
    }
}
```